# Getting href from HTMLDocument in HTMLKit

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to get the attribute href from an HTMLDocument in HTMLKit ([github](https://github.com/iabudiab/HTMLKit))

This is the code:

```
HTMLDocument *document = [HTMLDocument documentWithString:tempPage];
NSArray *articles = [document querySelectorAll:@"div.inner-article>a"];
for(HTMLDocument *article in articles){
    printf("%s\n\n", [article.outerhtml UTF8String]);
}
```

The documentation isn't very clear about this. I can clearly see the href with this for loop but I need to extract it further. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to access attributes dictionary, something like that :

```
let allAElements = htmldoc.querySelector("[class^='styles_tagcloud']")?.querySelectorAll("a")

  allAElements!.forEach({ (element) in
     print("Href >>> ", element.attributes.value(forKey: "href"))
  })
```